# Set value from nested Class GSON

Tags: android, gson

I'm trying to use GSON library for my first App.

I have a problem with a Class.

I return from my backend a JSonArray like this:

```
[
 {'id':1, 'className':{'id':1}  },
 {'id':2, 'className':{'id':2}  }
]
```

And I have 2 class on my App:

```
public class Class1{
  private int id;
  private Class2 className;
  private int classNameId;

  public Class1(){
   //function set that return error
   setClassNameId(className.getId())
  }
}

public class Class2{
  private int id;
  private int function getId(){
   return id;
  }
}
```

the problem is that when I try:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Class1>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Class1> classess= gson.fromJson(JsonArrayString, listType);
```

It return an exception in Class1 constructor on:

```
setClassNameId(className.getId())
```

because `className` is **null**.

So Is possible get value from child class with GSon and set on Constructor?

Comment: use this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for make model class

Comment: The Class1 constructor will be called first of settting the value of className, it will always be null, remove the setClassNameId and move it somewhere else

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate the `classNameId` in your main class? you can just expose a method that read the inner class value. The null pointer there is to be expected.

Comment: thankyou all, I have followed the Daniele's hint.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Class1 {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("className")
    private ClassName className;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    public static class ClassName {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("id")
        private int id;
    }
}
```

example:

```
String JsonArrayString = "[ { 'id': 1, 'className': { 'id': 1 } }, { 'id': 2, 'className': { 'id': 2 } } ]";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Class1>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Class1> classess= gson.fromJson(JsonArrayString, listType);
```